# Invoking a SQL Procedure in the database via VBA code

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have an **SQL query which takes up a parameter** stored in the db. I want to invoke the same from VBA code which is running on the same db. I am using MS Access for my work.

So for example consider, I have an SQL query 'Q' which takes a parameter 'p', I intend to invoke this SQL query from my VBA code 'C' , which also naturally involves passing this parameter 'p' to the query.

Help much appreciated
Soham

Comment: how are you connecting to the database? ODBC? What have you tried?

Comment: its a DAO database. I am just working with hard coded SQL query inside the VBA code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few possibilities here.

Let us say it is a SELECT query built on a form that holds the parameters to be used and that the input is safe:

```
s = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE AText ='" & Me.MyText & "'"
```

This can be used like so:

```
Forms!SomeForm.RecordSource = s
```

Or

```
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("NewQuery", s)
```

However, the above can be done in other, better ways.

Let us say it is a ACTION query run from a form that holds the parameters to be used and that the input is safe:

```
s = "UPDATE MyTable Set AText ='" & Me.MyText & "'"
```

Then

```
Set db = CurrentDB
db.Execute s, dbFailOnError
```

Or you can use a temporary query, which can be safer:

```
'Temporary query
s = "UPDATE MyTable Set AText = MyRext"

Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", s)

qdf.Parameters!MyText = Me.MyText
qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
```

Something similar to the above would also be suitable for an existing query.

You can also pass the parameter to a procedure, in which case Me.MyText becomes a variable, or you can use Inputbox, which is rarely a good idea.

After that, there is the whole world of ADO.

Comment: Many thanks. I am working with hard coded queries inside the VBA code. I will try to incorporate some of these methods. Manythanks